# Jquery $().each method obscures 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a Javascript object that contains a function that executes a jQuery `each` method like the following:

```
function MyClass {

  Method1 = function(obj) { 
    // Does something here
  }

  Method2 = function() {
    $(".SomeClass").each(function() {

       // 1          2
       this.Method1(this);

    });
  }

}
```

Which object is each `THIS` referring to?  jQuery is referring to the item returned from the `each` iteration.  However, I would like `This[1]` to refer to the containing class...

How can I refer to the containing class from within the jQuery loop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
function MyClass {
     Method1 = function(obj) {
         //do something here
     } 

     Method2 = function () {
          var containingClass = this;
          $(".SomeClass").each(function () {
             containingClass.Method1(this);
           });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please scope the containingClass variable to the function using the var keyword.  If you don't it will go in the global namespace.

Comment: Throw a var on that ContainingClass assignment, and this is gold..  to the point, and a simple modification of my posted code.

Comment: What about when I need to do something like `$(.SomeClass).click(function(){this.Method1()/*and some other code here*/});`?

Answer (score 12):

From http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each:

> This means that every time the
>   passed-in function is executed (which
>   is once for every element matched) the
>   'this' keyword points to the specific
>   DOM element. Note that 'this' does not
>   point to a jQuery object.

Personally, I prefer using explicit parameters. This way, it is more easily readable:

```
$('#rotfl').each(function(index, domObject)
{
   var jQueryObject = $(domObject);
   // code
});
```

To answer your question: JavaScript has <strike>dynamic</strike> static scope. You can do the following:

```
var that = this;
$('#rotfl').each(function(index, domObject)
{
   var jQueryObject = $(domObject);
   that.DoSomething();
   // code
});
```

Comment: Urm, don't you mean lexical scope, not dynamic?

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing isn't an issue with jQuery or its **`each()`** method - it is it what some people consider to be a design error in JavaScript - a nested function should "inherit" the context of the previous scope, so 'this' in a nested function should be equal to 'this' in its parent scope unless purposefully called from within a different context (using **`apply()`** or **`call()`**).

To get around this you need to assign 'this' to a variable before the nested function so that you have another way to reference it.

Comment: It is indeed to do with jQuery.each(), which works by using call() (in the most common case) or apply() and thus changes the object that *this* refers to.

Comment: Yes, but even if jQuery didn't call()/apply() the function 'this' still wouldn't be what was expected. Try it (function(){(function(){ alert(!!this.works); /* Doesn't exist */ })()}).call({works:true});

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery 1.3.3, you will be able to manually set the context for event handlers and such.

[jQuery Edge: Bind with a Different “this”](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/05/12/jquery-edge-bind-with-a-different-this)

In the meanwhile, the various techniques here (aliasing "this", using call/apply) are common practise.  Peter Higgins of Dojo has also made a [jQuery.hitch plugin](http://think-robot.com/2009/06/hitch-object-oriented-event-handlers-with-jquery/), which serves the same need.